# Bulk MIgration from MongoDB to PostgreSQL using MoSql

Tags: mongodb, postgresql

Hi I need to migrate my MongoDB into PostgreSQL.I used **MoSql tool** for that purpose. I created a collection map as following and saved in `test.yaml` file.

```
  test_db:
  check_collection:
    :columns:
    - id:
      :source: _id
      :type: TEXT
    - user_name:
      :source: user_name
      :type: TEXT
    - action_time:
      :source: action_time
      :type: TIMESTAMP
    :meta:
      :table: check_collection
      :extra_props: true
```

where `test_db` is my MongoDB and `check_collection` is my collection..and execute this using mosql and its working fine.All my raws inside check_collection is copied to PostgreSQL.

My question is that how to convert my all collections in mongoDB into PostgreSQL using a single test.yaml file? I have around 50+ collections in my project, so creating 50 yaml independent file is not a good idea.

Comment: Does the 50 collections have different structure?

Comment: yes...all collections have different schema